How can I play music over different channels in Python?
I have a 2-out device ("5: Kulaklıklar (Redmi Buds 5 Stere (2 out)").
I should be able to play asynchronous music over each channel like first channel music1.mp3 and second channel music2.mp3.
I tried using the sounddevice library but the first track is stopped when the second track starts.
I want to start a second track asynchronously at some later point in time on a different channel without stopping the other track.
def play_music(file_path, channel):
    data, fs = sf.read(file_path)
    mono_data = np.mean(data, axis=1)
    sd.play(mono_data, fs,mapping=[channel] ,device=5)
    sd.wait()

thread1=threading.Thread(target=play_music, args=('Musics\music1.mp3',1))
thread1.start()

time.sleep(2)

thread2=threading.Thread(target=play_music, args=('Musics\music2.mp3',2))
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()

